# Best approach to display images in a jsp page

Tags: java, image, jsp, web, servlet-3.0

I have a web site that displays almost 50 images per page. All these images are stored in my server's hdd and I have mapped on web.xml to display from there. For instance when an img src is img/1.jpg my server goes c:/images/1.jpg. However, when a single user visits the site, I see 50 requests on my access logs like this :

```
"GET /img/489310.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 89759 
"GET /img/490112.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 56986 
"GET /img/493460.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 4893 
"GET /img/491843.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 85365 
"GET /img/493515.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 26986 
"GET /img/493516.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 49199 
"GET /img/493359.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 9863 
"GET /img/493346.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 5317 
"GET /img/493294.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 5259 
"GET /img/493347.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 30452 
"GET /img/493357.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 13701 
"GET /img/493193.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 6492 
"GET /img/493352.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 34049
```

I am little bit nervous to see that and worry about what happens when 100 concurrent users visit my site.

All purpose of my page is to display images. What is the best approach to display images in a jsp page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal. Don't worry about it. Modern browsers and web servers can transfer multiple images over the same HTTP connection, so 50 requests doesn't mean 50 separate connections.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Should I use a servlet architecture that convert images to byte arrays and cache them then display from there ? Or classic file display is the proper way ?

Comment: @ftb If you want caching and your images are static then its better to use http server or proxy cache instead of caching in the JVM.

Comment: @Gas Is it like Varnish ? can you suggest any way to apply http server or proxy cache ?

Comment: @anL Yes, something like Varnish. Most of the application servers provides some kind of plugins that allows to connect them with front end http servers. Then you can deploy some of the static content to the http server and do some caching there if needed for example using mod_cache https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_cache.html